# Use same instance of $modal in angularjs with ui boostrap

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Does anyone know if it is possible to open a modal using $modal.open() and save this instance of the modal to be opened again later?

Comment: When you say "Save the instance", what are you trying to save inside? The modal just renders whatever you give it.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, bootstrap's `$modal.open()` just **shows** your modal view, and `$modal.close()` just **hides** it...
So I don't fully understand what you do mean by "save this instance of the modal"...

See also [docs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).